# What makes following question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

The following question is described as off-topic [Which property of Scala's type-system make it Turing-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497786/which-property-of-scalas-type-system-make-it-turing-complete) , but I have no idea why?

Is it not related to programming? Shouldn't it be moved to another Stack Exchange site instead of put as off-topic?

Comment: It can't be moved.  You can only migrate questions younger than 60 days.  But I don't see how it is off-topic.  However, the question seems much too broad.  I don't know Scala, but just based on the first sentence of the answer, you would have to write a novel to completely answer the question, so should still be closed.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified where it should be moved.

Comment: The title may be part of the problem here. It seems unlikely that any particular property of Scala's type-system in itself makes it Turing-complete. The question text makes it perfectly clear—but if you're concerned with how to practically get a good answer or good close reason (as appropriate) for your questions, a title that will immediately invite a "duh" reaction before people even start reading will probably predispose some of them to answer/vote dismissively instead of putting the care into it that you'd want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a *programming* problem, it's a *computer science* problem.

[There is in fact a site for computer science problems.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

As was noted in comments, the question is too old to be migrated, so while you could re-ask it somewhere where it would be on topic, you couldn't *migrate* it anywhere.

(Note that I'm not a member of CS.SE; I'm not sure if the question is suitable for that site, just that it would be on topic there.  I don't know if it's appropriately scoped, or otherwise meets the other criteria they may have for their questions, so check their help center before asking.)

Comment: But a question like that is better to be closed as too broad, than off topic, correct? Assuming you can't move it to another site.

Comment: @DanielFath It's both, so it doesn't matter which is used.  I see no *problem* with closing an off topic question as being off topic.